# Difference between jquery.simulate.js and jQuery event methods?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jquery-ui, testing

The jQuery UI source library contains a [jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/medihack/jquery-ui/blob/ticker/tests/jquery.simulate.js) file for simulating mouse and keyboard events. What is the benefit of using that simulate function instead of using [jQuery event methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) when testing jQuery UI stuff?

Comment: Zardoz , jquery event methods might be having all the basic needed stuff, but plugin might be having much more advanced stuff..as itis excusively did for events.

Comment: @if you couldn't do something by yourself and if someone else already done that for you , then you can go for ...plugin

Comment: @gov ... I don't see any advanced stuff in there. It seems to me that both trigger the same events. Maybe someone of the jQuery UI team is around here to answer that question.

Comment: if you can achieve everything with jquery event methods , then ingore the plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jquery.simulate.js` file is used only to simulate events - it doesn't provide a full event management system like jQuery does. This means, it creates a fake event object, and then sends this event to the DOM. This can be compared to jQuery's `.trigger()` method, which does a similar thing.

However, there are many properties on an event object that can be modified, including whether it should bubble or not, what the source element was, whether any special keys were pressed, the exact x and y locations the mouse was clicked, and so on. jQuery hides this from us when we call `.trigger()`, by setting only the necessary properties to some default values. `jquery.simulate.js` on the other hand is designed for **testing** (notice that the file is located under "jquery-ui/tests/"). For testing purposes, you'd want more fine-grained control over the event object to better mimic real user interaction.

Long story short, unless you're doing testing, most likely you won't need `jquery.simulate.js` at all. Even if you want some of the functionalities it provides, be warned that the file isn't officially part of the jquery-ui library.

Comment: -1. You have missed out on a very important point here. .trigger() would call only the event handlers, if any, for the keyboard events and the actual keyboard events would be triggered. For eg - if i need to trigger the backspace keyboard event such that the last character of an element gets deleted, then trigerring the keypress/keydown/keyup of event which keyCode=8 wont work. Using this jquery.simulate.js can do this.https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext has been built over thsi lib.

Comment: Please lemme know if by using .trigger() you are able to achieve the actual keypress. I need to implement the same.